# PHP to Increase counter by 1 and save in a txt file

Tags: php

I am trying my php script to read the current count from "counter.txt" file and add 1 and save it back in the counter text file.

```
$filename = 'counter.txt';

// create the file if it doesn't exist
if (!file_exists($filename)) {
    $counter_file = fopen($filename, "w");
    fwrite($counter_file, "0");
    $counter = 0;
} else {
    $counter_file = fopen($filename, "r");

    // will read the first line
    $counter = fgets($counter_file);
}

// increase $counter
$counter++;

// echo counter
echo $counter;

// save the increased counter
fwrite($counter_file, "0");

// close the file
fclose($counter_file);
```

The script reads and echos the number fine but it doesn't save the file with the increased number.

Please help

Comment: This line could be the culprit - fwrite($counter_file, "0"); - change "0" to $counter

Comment: `$counter_file = fopen($filename, "r");` __r__ for __read__

Comment: You might find it easier to use the `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents` functions, they're a much cleaner interface.

Comment: ^^ would also reduce the code to 1 line..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add a string and a number in a sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47853583/add-a-string-and-a-number-in-a-sum)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may not be helpful if this is just a learning exercise to familiarize yourself with the various file functions, but this could be a lot simpler using `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents`.

```
$file = 'counter.txt';

// default the counter value to 1
$counter = 1;

// add the previous counter value if the file exists    
if (file_exists($file)) {
    $counter += file_get_contents($file);
}

// write the new counter value to the file
file_put_contents($file, $counter);
```

Of course, whether or not this will work either this way or the way you're trying to do it totally depends on whether or not the file is writable, so you'll also need to be sure its permissions are set properly.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
$counter = 1;
$file_name = 'test.'.$counter.'.ext';
if (file_exists($file_name)) {
    $counter++;
    fopen('test'.$counter.'.ext' , "w");
}
else {
    fopen('test'.$counter.'.ext' , "w");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

$filename = 'counter.txt';

// create the file if it doesn't exist
if (!file_exists($filename)) {
    $counter_file = fopen($filename, "w");
    fwrite($counter_file, "1");
    fclose($counter_file);
} else {
    $counter_file = fopen($filename, "w+");
    $fsize = filesize($filename);
    // will read the whole file
    $counter = (int) fread($counter_file, $fsize);
    $counter++;

    fwrite($counter_file, $counter);
    fclose($counter_file);
}
```